# double variable not able to hold onto values

Tags: iphone

i have a double variable in my application and i update some values to it in viewDidLoad method and want to use it later in one of the delegate method of tableview but the variable is not able to retain the value. I am declaring it as follows:

```
double subTtl;
@property(nonatomic,assign) double subTtl;
```

mycode for viewdidLoad

```
subTtl = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<[pizzaAppDel.arrOrders count]; i++) {
    [pizzaAppDel.arrOrderDetails addObject:@"1"];
    subTtl = subTtl + [[(NSDictionary*)[pizzaAppDel.arrOrders objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"price"] doubleValue];
}
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",subTtl]);
```

This is how i m using it in my tableview delegate method:

```
lblTtlPrice.text = [@"Subtotal:  $" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",subTtl]];
```

i am synthesising it in .m file and saving some values, i can see the values inside the variable but when i try to use it later i get nothing from it, variable returns empty.

Comment: You should post your viewDidLoad method. Also, make sure it's being called by placing a breakpoint on it.

Comment: How do you use it? There is no such thing as an *"empty"* `double`.

Comment: please check above code i have updated it.

Comment: in which order are the delegate method + viewDidLoad called, maybe viewDidLoad is called *after* the delegate method? And I assume the NSLog in view did load does display the correct value?

Comment: no the delegate mathods are called later, i have checked it in nslog that it have values when it is in viewdidload but the variable loses the values when it reaches the delegate methods and i have checked the value is not being updated in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If subTtl is an instance variable of your view controller and you want to access it from another instance (say, your app delegate), you will need a reference to the view controller. You can then access subTtl as a property:

```
lblTtlPrice.text = [@"Subtotal:  $" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",viewController.subTtl]];
```

Comment: hi tom, i am using the variable subTtl within the same view controller